# Managing class scope in swift

Tags: ios, swift, class

I have two classes: `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

`ClassA` is a singleton which looks like this:

```
class ClassA {
    class var sharedInstance: ClassA {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = ClassA()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    private (set) var classB = ClassB()       

    init() {     
    }    
}
```

`ClassA` can only initialize the `ClassB`, which works fine. My `ClassB` looks like this:

```
class ClassB {

    init() {

    }   
}
```

Now I want `ClassB` to only be accessible by `ClassA` and not by any other classes in the project. For example, `ClassC` should not be able to initialize `ClassB` like this:

```
class ClassC {
   private var classB = ClassB()
}
```

How do I enforce this behaviour?

Comment: Please not you don't need to define a `struct` to create a `Singleton Class`. Look this `class ClassA { static let sharedInstance = ClassA() }`

Comment: You should also make the singleton's initialiser private

Answer (score 2):

You could make class B a private class within A, like this:

```
class ClassA {
    private var classB = ClassB()  
    private class ClassB{
         init() {
        }
    }

    class var sharedInstance: ClassA {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = ClassA()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }      

    init() {            
    }        
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you have many such classes, you could create extensions for each needed dependency:

```
extension ClassA {
    private class ClassC {
        init() {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice solution but lets say I have alot of class which provide different fucntionality then my ClassA would become a mess ultimately containing a lot of code

Comment: I can't use the base class ClassA variable inside ClassB if Class B is declared as extension of ClassA

Comment: @hariszaman Usually, you would only use ClassC in the extension. Put all the needed functions in the extension as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112424/discussion-between-simplebob-and-hariszaman).